# Is ArrayList in C# a good equivalent for ArrayList in Java?

Tags: c#, java, arraylist

I'm new to C# -- under 50 lines of code in.

So the question is ArrayList in C# is a good substitute for ArrayList in Java.

Here are some differences that I've noticed:

1. ArrayList in C# does not seem to support Generics -- this was surprising and it leads me to believe that I'm looking at an older collection class.
2. I can't seem to be able to do an in-place replace of an element like I can in Java using set(index, value)
3. What is more confusing is that to access element n in C# I have to use the array accessor [n] as opposed to get(n)
4. Further thought I can access the element in c# using [] I cannot set say myarraylist[n]="bla"

So this leads me to believe that I'm missing something here - perhaps something about the C# design philosophy.

I've tried digging around the Internet for C# for Java programmers but I still do not have good answers to this question.

Comment: `ArrayList` in C# is a relic of the days before generics. You probably want `List<T>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for generics, that is roughly equivalent to Java `ArrayList`

> The List(Of T) class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class.
>   It implements the IList(Of T) generic interface by using an array
>   whose size is dynamically increased as required.

Comment: What about underlying implementation -- is it a linked in, Array ... can I tweak that?

Comment: @JasonC, just added that to my answer as well :)

Comment: @Habib what if I need the underlying implementation to be say LinkedList for Performance reasons -- say my List's size is going to vary widely ?

Comment: @user1172468, then you can use [LinkedList<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: @user1172468 - please remember that performance optimisations of the kind your referring shouldn't be attempted until you have good analytics indicating that it is indeed the implementation of the collection algorithm as opposed to bad design around the class.

Comment: @PreetSangha, yes and no - the reason I brought up the point was that very often I will know in advance if a certain underlying implementation will have problems with severe expansion and contraction of the collection because I often deal with such problems.

Comment: @user1172468 - in other words you have the analytics!